# Where is the default cache path for cefsharp (chromiumwebbrowser)?

Tags: cefsharp

I am using cefsharp's chromiumwebbrowser, and I want to test it separately with and without cache.

So I'm trying to test while deleting the cache in the path, but I can't figure out the default path.

Is there a default cache path of chromiumwebbrowser or a method to delete the cache?

Comment: See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/84.4.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefSettingsBase_CachePath.htm the default is empty. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown for example.

Comment: There is no direct API for clearing the cache,  you can use DevTools to achieve this, please ask as a separate question.